# Is the Symmetry factor different in Path integral Formalism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, path-integral, feynman-diagrams

Is the Symmetry factor different in Path integral Formalism and the Perturbation theory (canonical) formalism? For example, the order-1 4-point cross X diagram in the $\phi^4$ theory has symmetry factor of $4!$ using Path integral Formalism, but has symmetry factor of $1$ using Wick contraction in perturbation formalism. Why different?

Comment: It has a symmetry factor of 1 in both cases

Comment: Could you write your defn of a symmetry factor?